# Flow of the vector field $(X, Y)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

For a manifold $M$, let us write $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ for the space of vector fields on $M$ (that is, sections of the tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$).

Now, given $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $Y\in\mathfrak{X}(N)$ then $(X, Y):M\times N\longrightarrow TM\times TN\simeq T(M\times N)$ gives us a vector field $Z:=(X, Y)\in \mathfrak{X}(M\times N)$. Is it true that:

$(a)$ The flow of $Z$, $\Phi^Z:M\times N\times I\longrightarrow M\times N$ is given by $$\Phi^Z(x, y, t)=(\Phi^X(x, t), \Phi^Y(y, t)),$$ where $\Phi^X:M\times I\longrightarrow M$ and $\Phi^Y:N\times I\longrightarrow N$ are the flows of $X$ and $Y$, respectively;

$(b)$ The Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_Z:C^\infty(M\times N)\longrightarrow C^\infty(M\times N)$ is given by $$\mathcal{L}_{Z}(f)(p, q)=\mathcal{L}_X(f(\cdot, q))(p)+\mathcal{L}_Y(f(p, \cdot))(q)?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{d}{dt} f\circ \Phi^Z= df\ (X,Y)  =df\ (X,0) + df\ (Y,0)=\frac{d}{dt} f\circ \Phi^X + \frac{d}{dt} f\circ \Phi^Y$$

Answer (score 1):

As it might be useful for someone else I'm posting my (partial) answer.

The vector part of the vector field $(X, Y)$ in a point $(p, q)\in M\times N$ is given by

\begin{align*}
(X, Y)_{(p, q)}:=(d\jmath_q)_p(X_p)+(d\jmath_p)_q(Y_q).
\end{align*}

where $\jmath_q:M\longrightarrow M\times N$, $p\longmapsto (p, q)$ and $\jmath_p:N\longrightarrow M\times N$, $q\longmapsto (q, p)$.

Consequently:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{(X, Y)}(f)(p, q)&=df(X, Y)(p, q)\\
&=df_{(p, q)}((X, Y)_{(p, q)})\\
&=df_{(p, q)}((d\jmath_q)_p(X_p)+(d\jmath_p)_q(Y_q))\\
&=df_{(p, q)}((d\jmath_q)_p(X_p))+df_{(p, q)}((d\jmath_p)_q(Y_q))\\
&=d(f\circ \jmath_q)_p(X_p)+d(f\circ \jmath_p)_q(Y_q)\\
&=(df_q)_p(X_p)+(df_p)_q(Y_q)\\
&=\mathcal{L}_X(f_q)(p)+\mathcal{L}_Y(f_p)(q).
\end{align*}